# SQL Server sp_send_dbmail not sending body in email to sms

Tags: sql-server, database-mail

I am attempting to send an email to a text message number using the sp_send_dbmail stored procedure in SQL Server (both 2008 R2 and 2016 give the same results). Even if I send a test email from the server test tool, the body of the email is not sent in the text. If I send the same test to a normal email address, the body displays correctly. How do I get the body to display in the text message?

[image: Test Email]

[image: Resulting Text]

Comment: SQL Server doesn't natively send text messages, and emails don't get sent to a mobile natively if you put a mobile number instead of an email address; email and SMS are 2 different technologies. I think the problem is not SQL Server, but what ever you are using to convert an email to be sent as an SMS.

Comment: We're using Exchange 2016 to process the email. I would think Exchange is able to handle it correctly if it can send it to an email address correctly. I also tried sending an email from my email address to my phone through outlook and it worked.